# margin-top on an internal div is getting applied to an external div.

Tags: html, css

Here's a fiddle I setup illustrating the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/rgfjL/13/

Here's the code

HTML

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="contact-form" class="clearfix">
        <p> asdsasadsad </p>
    </div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
div.body {
  display: block;
  height: 800px;
  width: 1024px;
  background: #474747;
}

div.contact-form {
  display: block;
  background-color:#F2F7F9;
  height: 600px;
  width:465px;
  padding:20px;
  margin: 250px auto;
  border: 6px solid #8FB5C1;
 -moz-border-radius:15px;
 -webkit-border-radius:15px;
  border-radius:15px;
}​
```

As you can see in the fiddle, the form div is flush against the top of the body div. Changing top margin on form pushes both of them down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is Collapsing Margins

```
div.body {
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rgfjL/15/

more info http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Answer (score 0):

Apply `overflow: hidden;` to the class `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Using overflow:hidden; on div.body will cause div.contact-form to be cut off.

Instead of a margin-top on div.contact-form, add padding-top on div.body.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'll have to make it work : http://jsfiddle.net/rgfjL/16/

```
<div class="body">
            <div class="contact-form" class="clearfix">
                <p> asdsasadsad </p>
    </div>
<div>

div.body {
    display: block;
    height: 800px;
    width: 1024px;
    background: #474747;
    padding-top:250px;
}


div.contact-form {
    display: block;
    background-color:#F2F7F9;
    height: 600px;
    width:465px;
    padding:20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 6px solid #8FB5C1;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
}
```